# What is the F/cm^2 for a commercially available supercapacitor?

Tags: supercapacitor

What is the F/cm^2 for a commercially available supercapacitor? Much of the literature is on newer types of carbon, such as graphene, but are commercially available supercapacitors based on activated carbon?

http://www.pnas.org/content/suppl/2015/03/22/1420398112.DCSupplemental (Download Supporting Information (PDF)) 
In this article published on March 23, 2015, the F/cm^2 is 300mF/cm^2 (.3F/cm^2) for activated carbon (Table S1, p.16), yet references the information from an older article. The reference is to:
Simon P, Gogotsi Y (2008) Materials for electrochemical capacitors. Nature Materials 7: 845-854.

http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/368/1923/3457
The authors of the older article state, "Double-layer capacitance for carbon materials in liquid electrolytes is in the range of 5 to 20 μF cm−2, depending on the electrolyte." in this different but more up to date 2010 article.

I have not unraveled a supercapacitor, but the range of 5 to 20 μF cm−2 seems rather low compared to the small size of supercapacitors commercially available, but is the .3F/cm^2 stated in the more recent article accurate?

Comment: Are you comparing like with like? If the lower value supports a higher operating voltage or lower ESR it may still be a better (higher energy-density or higher power-density) product.

Comment: No, not comparing like with like.  Trying to get the range for F/cm^2 for commercial available supercapacitors.  The 5 to 20 μF cm−2 seems too low, but could have been the value when the reference was made (> 5 years).  Thin supercapacitors an inch in diameter can be a capacitance of one Farad (see picture here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor#Operating_voltage).  At 20 μF cm−2, one Farad would be 50,000 cm^2?

Comment: Getting a F/cm^2 range for commercially available supercapacitors is more difficult than I thought.